# Input string, output object equal to string

Tags: python

I am using a discord bot to run some programs on a server of mine. Presently I have it set up so that if I say "Bot, start XGamingServer" it will take the string, splice it to get the third word "XGamingServer", and then will run it through a separate 'if' statement for every server it has stored. I was wondering if there is a better way to organise this so that it will look at all the instances of server I have and if "XGamingServer" matches any objects self.name , it would return the object.

I've tried the large trees of if,elif statements, which is incredibly bulky but does get the job done. I've also tried making a list of all the worlds and trying to compare it that way, but that bugged out and I didn't get very far.

```
class World:
    def __init__(self, name, runfile):
        self.name = name
        self.runfile = runfile
    def Run(self):
        ## The code that runs the server
        pass

MainWorld = World("MainWorld","Examplefile1")
SpinOffWorld = World("SpinOffWorld", "DifferentStartFile")

# Actual Discord Bot code, problem not unique to the discord bot
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("Bot, start"):
        findProgram = msg.content.split(" ")
        ServerKind = findProgram[2]
        if ServerKind = "MainWorld":
            MainWorld.Run()
            ## Other code
        elif ServerKind = "SpinOffWorld":
            SpinfOffWorld.Run()
            ## OtherCode
        elif ServerKind = "AnyOtherServer":
            AnyOtherServer.Run()
            ## OtherCode
        else:
            await client.say(msg.channel, "Sorry, Server Not Recognised")
```

Like I said, this code *does* work and everything runs properly, but there are 3 lines in every if statement, and they're identical except for the world to run. It really increases the size of the code unnecessarily as I have around 6 servers right now and would like to add more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a *variable* number of objects (whether they are strings, integers, or user-defined classes), consider using `list`s, `dict`s, `tuple`s... all those nice little containers. A `dict` seems appropriate here:

```
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("Bot, start"):
        findProgram = msg.content.split(" ")
        ServerKind = findProgram[2]

        servers = {"MainWorld": MainWorld, "SpinOffWorld": SpinOffWorld, "AnyOtherServer": AnyOtherServer}
        if ServerKind in servers:
            servers[ServerKind].Run()
            # ...
        else:
            await client.say(msg.channel, "Sorry, Server Not Recognised")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all server classes have a common base class `Server`:

```
server = globals().get(ServerKind)
if isinstance(server, Server):
    server.Run()
    # ...
else:
    await client.say(msg.channel, "Sorry, Server Not Recognised")
```